# json stream to elasticsearch through logstash

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a json stream, that i want to pass to elasticsearch through logstash. I understand I need an input, then json filter, then output to elasticsearch. But I don't know what is the appropriate input to use for logstash. My json stream is a URL at **localhost:8083**, and looks like this:

> {"node":1,"road_density":27,"speed":17.750372299924493,"car_count":3,"temperature":55,"cpu":40,"memory":49,"timestamp":"6/21/2015 1:12:32 PM"}
>   {"node":1,"road_density":38,"speed":132.35753105953336,"car_count":1,"temperature":67,"cpu":91,"memory":98,"timestamp":"6/21/2015 1:12:32 PM"}
>   {"node":1,"road_density":0,"speed":123.76824188511819,"car_count":0,"temperature":51,"cpu":17,"memory":15,"timestamp":"6/21/2015 1:12:32 PM"}
>   {"node":1,"road_density":85,"speed":72.68045444507152,"car_count":1,"temperature":60,"cpu":34,"memory":68,"timestamp":"6/21/2015 1:12:33 PM"}
>   {"node":1,"road_density":89,"speed":69.51827178243548,"car_count":2,"temperature":40,"cpu":67,"memory":12,"timestamp":"6/21/2015 1:12:33 PM"}
>   {"node":1,"road_density":48,"speed":45.43173309415579,"car_count":3,"temperature":45,"cpu":5,"memory":48,"timestamp":"6/21/2015
>   1:12:34 PM"}
>   {"node":1,"road_density":13,"speed":104.68090719077736,"car_count":3,"temperature":57,"cpu":32,"memory":22,"timestamp":"6/21/2015 1:12:35 PM"}

Comment: How are you planning to stream the json? via TCP/UDP port? via pipe? from a file?

Comment: when u open the link mentioned, you get the lines above increasing continuously..